# DOCKER installation error - libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.99)

Tags: software-installation, docker

According `docker` installation procedure on `Ubuntu` I got a problem:

```
kp@maas:~$ sudo apt install docker-engine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-engine : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.99) but 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anybody has same problem and maybe knows how to solve this?

### /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list is correct ?

```
# Ubuntu Precise
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-precise main
# Ubuntu Trusty
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
# Ubuntu Vivid
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-vivid main
# Ubuntu Wily
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-wily main
```

### output of : apt-cache policy docker-engine libdevmapper1.02.1

```
kp@maas:~$ apt-cache policy docker-engine libdevmapper1.02.1
docker-engine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.3-0~wily
  Version table:
     1.8.3-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.3-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.3-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
     1.8.3-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packag                                        es
     1.8.2-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.2-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.2-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
     1.8.2-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packag                                        es
     1.8.1-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.1-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
     1.8.1-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packag                                        es
     1.8.0-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.0-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
     1.8.0-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packag                                        es
     1.7.1-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.1-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
     1.7.1-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packag                                        es
     1.7.0-0~vivid 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Package                                        s
libdevmapper1.02.1:
  Installed: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
kp@maas:~$
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy docker-engine libdevmapper1.02.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the repositories for **four** Ubuntu releases. Your Ubuntu release is Vivid. Therefore correct the problem via

```
sudo sed -i '/wily/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo sed -i '/trusty/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo sed -i '/precise/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Comment: Thank's ;-)
I thought that must have all kind of repo ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to have only your Ubuntu Version repo in docker.list. In my case, I use Ubuntu Utopic, so my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` is:

```
# Ubuntu Utopic
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-utopic main
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is specifying which version you wish to install.

See a list of all available:

```
$ apt-cache policy docker-engine
docker-engine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.0-0~wily
  Version table:
     1.12.0-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.0-0~precise 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-precise/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.2-0~wily 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-wily/main amd64 Packages
     ...
```

Then to install a specific on for your ubuntu trusty:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.12.0-0~trusty
```